Flutter DeepLink - GoRouter
I implemented go_router to use deep links in my app, but for some paths, I need to ignore the deep link and open them in the browser.
For example, when the user clicks the following URL https://example.com/login, the deep link works fine and opens my Flutter app on the specific page.
However, when the user clicks on https://example.com/privacy, I need this link to open in the default browser and not in my app.
I've been searching for a solution, but the result is always the same: the link always opens in my app.
I tried using the launchUrl package, but the result is still the same:
launchUrl(Uri, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
I've tried all the available LaunchMode options, but nothing seems to work.
I need open some paths in browser app and others in my app.
The paths are some examples, I need all the paths that are not specifying in the route map go to the web page
I implemented go_router library

It would be helpful for you to post your apple-app-site-association and/or your assetlinks.json as well as discuss which platform you are using.
Regarding deep links in Flutter there are important differences with Android and iOS to understand. Apple provides the ability to exclude certain paths via support in their apple-app-site-association. More info can be seen on their docs with an example on how to exclude.
In Android 12, changes were made that impact the ability for a developer to route a url to the external browser aka the web. If you have declared that your Android App Links to accept /privacy then Android will always route the user back to your application.
You will either need to handle this route in your application or do not declare the route of /privacy in your asset-links file for Android.

Currently, I don't have an assetlink file for Android published on any server. I couldn't find information suggesting that I should declare routes in this file. What I did see is that in the manifest, I could specify which prefixes or suffixes to use, but this wouldn’t apply in my case since I need all undeclared routes (in code) to be redirected to the website. That's why I was using launchUrl, but when launching it using this library, it returns to the app in an infinite loop.

@RobertoMacías, the infinite loop you are seeing is because of Android's changes in Android 12. Android OS understands that your app is handling all routes to example.com and thus routes back to your app.
The information that Sukaina Ahmed posted below would work but then your user will see the url in a separate view. It's a solution but could introduce other UX issues.
I also misspoke about the asset links.json, it does not handle routes. There is an open issue with Android about this lack of exclude support but there is no plan to fix. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/250089874

This work for me using url_launcher as follow:
  launchURL("https://example.com/privacy",mode:LaunchMode.inAppWebView );


I had used the line of code you shared with me, but it opens the website in a WebView that the user can't interact with, as it opens in full screen. I wanted to explore the possibility of launching it in the browser application.
